# Perl Regex for mathjax syntax

Tags: regex, perl, mathjax

I have a problem making a perl regex to change `\` character following these rules:

1. A matching sequence should start with `\(`
2. It should end with `\)`
3. Any `\` character in the previous matching sequence should be replaced with a double backslash `\\`

Example text reference:

```
Se la \probabilit&agrave; dell'evento\ A &egrave; \(\frac{3}{4} \) e la
probabilit&agrave; dell'evento B &egrave; \(\frac{1}{4}\)&nbsp;
\(\frac{3}{4} +\frac{3}{4}\)&nbsp;.
\(\frac{1}{4} - \frac{3}{4}\)&nbsp;.
\(\frac{3}{16}\)&nbsp;.
\(\frac{1}{2}\)&nbsp;.
```

Should become:

```
Se la \probabilit&agrave; dell'evento\ A &egrave; \\(\\frac{3}{4} \\) e la
probabilit&agrave; dell'evento B &egrave; \\(\\frac{1}{4}\\)&nbsp;
\\(\\frac{3}{4} +\\frac{3}{4}\\)&nbsp;.
\\(\\frac{1}{4} - \\frac{3}{4}\\)&nbsp;.
\\(\\frac{3}{16}\\)&nbsp;.
\\(\\frac{1}{2}\\)&nbsp;.
```

So far this is my best bet:

```
s/(\\\()(.*)(\\)(.*)(\\\))/\\\\\($2\\\\$4\\\\\)/mg
```

which produces:

```
Se la \probabilit&agrave; dell'evento\ A &egrave; \\(\\frac{3}{4} \\) e la
probabilit&agrave; dell'evento B &egrave; \\(\\frac{1}{4}\\)&nbsp;
\\(\frac{3}{4} +\\frac{3}{4}\\)&nbsp;.
\\(\frac{1}{4} - \\frac{3}{4}\\)&nbsp;.
\\(\\frac{3}{16}\\)&nbsp;.
\\(\\frac{1}{2}\\)&nbsp;.
```

As you can see

```
\\(\frac{3}{4} +\\frac{3}{4}\\)&nbsp;.
\\(\frac{1}{4} - \\frac{3}{4}\\)&nbsp;.
```

are wrong.

How can I modify my regex to accomodate my needs?

Comment: This would be a valid question if after your sample input and output it continued on with, "I tried using the following code: ....... but it failed to match the following condition: ......... .  How should I modify my code to accommodate that condition too?"  As written, it's a specification for work that needs to be done, not a question asking for guidance on code you're working on.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add my attempt so far, I just edited the question

Comment: It can be efficiently done with `$string =~ s/(?x)(?:(?!\A)\G[^\\]*\K\\|\\(?=\())(?=.*?(?<=\\)\))/\\\\/g;`

Comment: Good. I nominated the question for re-opening.

Comment: @sln I tested it and it seems to work in a perl script, I was trying my regex in regex101.com but it seems that it doesn't allow \G and \K, I was not aware about those options, I read perl doc, but I find it hard to understand. I'll test it more accurately tomorrow, now it's bed time :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting an updated regex from my original.

The original had a validation at the end for *all* escapes.
After looking at it, it can be sped up by only doing the validation
one time when it finds the opening block.

*At the bottom is a benchmark that compares the two methods.*

**Updated regex:**

`$str =~ s/(?s)(?:(?!\A)\G(?!\))[^\\]*\K\\|\\(?=\(.*?\\\)))/\\\\/g;`

[Formatted and tested:](http://www.regexformat.com)

```
 (?s)               # Dot-All modifier
 (?:                # Cluster start
      (?! \A )           # Not beginning of string
      \G                 # G anchor - If matched before, start at end of last match
      (?! \) )           # Last was an escape, so ')' ends the block
      [^\\]*             # Many non-escape's
      \K                 # Previous is not part of match
      \\                 # A lone escape
   |                   # or,
                         # New Block Check - 
      \\                 # A lone escape then,
      (?=                # One time Validation:
           \(                 #  an opening '('
           .*?                #  anything
           \\ \)              #  then a final '\)'
      )                  # -------------
 )                  # Cluster end
```

**Benchmark:**

Sample  `\( \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ \)`

Results

```
New Regex:   (?s)(?:(?!\A)\G(?!\))[^\\]*\K\\|\\(?=\(.*?\\\)))
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   31
Elapsed Time:    1.25 s,   1253.92 ms,   1253924 µs


Old Regex:   (?s)(?:(?!\A)\G[^\\]*\K\\|\\(?=\())(?=.*?(?<=\\)\))
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   31
Elapsed Time:    3.95 s,   3952.31 ms,   3952307 µs
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested @sln regex

```
s/(?x)(?:(?!\A)\G[^\\]*\K\\|\\(?=\())(?=.*?(?<=\\)\))/\\\\/g;
```

And it seems to work,although it remains an arcane mystery to me.

**Update with explanation**

[Formatted and tested:](http://www.regexformat.com)

```
 (?s)               # Inline Dot-All modifier
 (?:                # Cluster start
      (?! \A )           # Not beginning of string
      \G                 # G anchor - If matched before, start at end of last match
      [^\\]*             # Many non-escape's
      \K                 # Previous is not part of match
      \\                 # A lone escape
   |                   # or,
                         # Start of an opening '\('
      \\                 # A lone escape
      (?= \( )           #   followed by an open parenth
 )                  # Cluster end
 (?=                # Lookahead, each match validates a final '\)'
      .*? 
      (?<= \\ )
      \) 
 )
```

Comment: Change the `(?x)` to `(?s)`. It's not really a mystery. I'll update your post with an explanation.

Comment: I posted a quicker variant regex, if you're interested.